# Hyperlinking an Abbreviated Citation to its Reference in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, citing

I have a paper in which I cite another paper multiple times. In order to avoid repeating the same citation every time I make a reference to it, I cite it in full the first time around and then I abbreviate it and use it in rest of the paper. For example, this is the sentence that appears in my paper:

> Fernandez-Villaverde, Guerron-Quintana, Kuester and Rubio-Ramirez (2015) (hereafter FGKR) show that ...

How can I hyperlink 'FGKR' to the same reference in bibliography that its full form does? I want it to work just like the usual citations do with hyperref package in article class.

EDIT

Courtesy of OP's comments, I realized I should post an MWE. Here it is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\title{A Paper} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{fernandez2015fiscal,
title={Fiscal Volatility Shocks and Economic Activity},
author={Fern{\'a}ndez-Villaverde, Jes{\'u}s and Guerr{\'o}n-Quintana, Pablo 
and Kuester, Keith and Rubio-Ram{\'\i}rez, Juan},
journal={The American Economic Review},
volume={105},
number={11},
pages={3352--3384},
year={2015},
publisher={American Economic Association}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\citet*{fernandez2015fiscal} (FGKR now on) look at real effects of increased 
uncertainty surrounding fiscal policy and find that volatility shocks to 
fiscal policy in the US carried negative effects on investment, output, 
consumption and labor. The VAR estimated in FGKR \ldots

\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The output after I compile looks like this:

[image]

Here, the citation is correctly hyperlinked to the entry in the 'References' section. What I further want to do is to hyperlink every instance of 'FGKR' to the same entry in the 'References' section. How should I go about doing it?

Comment: If you are using `biblatex` you may want to look into `shorthand`. If you use `natbib`, you may be interested in `\defcitealias` and `\citetalias`/`\citepalias`. If you are using neither of these packages, you probably have to cook up something on your own. People will only be able to offer concrete advice if they know more about your document. Ideally you would show us short example document that demonstrates your bibliography/citation setup, a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864

Comment: @moewe, thanks for your time. I posted the MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading `natbib`, so you can use `\defcitealias{<key>}{<alias>}` to define an `<alias>` for `<key>` that can be printed with `\citetalias{<key>}` and `\citepalias{<key>}` instead of the normal citation label.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red]{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{fernandez2015fiscal,
  title   = {Fiscal Volatility Shocks and Economic Activity},
  author  = {Fern{\'a}ndez-Villaverde, Jes{\'u}s
             and Guerr{\'o}n-Quintana, Pablo
             and Kuester, Keith and Rubio-Ram{\'i}rez, Juan},
  journal = {The American Economic Review},
  volume  = {105},
  number  = {11},
  pages   = {3352--3384},
  year    = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}

\defcitealias{fernandez2015fiscal}{FGKR}

\begin{document}
\citet*{fernandez2015fiscal} (\citetalias{fernandez2015fiscal} from now on) 

\citetalias{fernandez2015fiscal} and \citepalias{fernandez2015fiscal}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fernández-Villaverde, Guerrón-Quintana, Kuester, and Rubio-Ramírez (2015) (FGKR from now on) FGKR and (FGKR)]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @moewe. One additional curiosity if I may. Is it possible to add URLs to my references? I did some search and experimenting but it seems ecta (Econometrica) style that I use does not permit URLs. Any way to bypass it?

Comment: @user523170 `ecta.bst` does indeed not have native support for URLs. You can either add it manually (or with `urlbst`) or you can give up and put the URL in `note` or `howpublished`. If you need more help with that I suggest you ask a new question.