# How to include URLs with ecta style?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperref, urls, urlbst

I am using `ecta` (Econometrica) style for references. I want to include URLs with them but `ecta` style does not support it. I tried using `note` and `howpublished` but it appears the `ecta` style overrides them. I also tried using `urlbst` package as suggested by @moewe [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497530/hyperlinking-an-abbreviated-citation-to-its-reference-in-bibliography) but it throws up the following error even though I use the commands `\usepackage{urlbst}` (I am compiling the document online):

[image]

Sans `urlbest` package, I don't get the error but URLs don't show up in my references:

[image]

Is there any way to include URLs with `ecta` style? Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\title{A Paper} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{fernandez2015fiscal,
title={Fiscal Volatility Shocks and Economic Activity},
author={Fern{\'a}ndez-Villaverde, Jes{\'u}s and Guerr{\'o}n-Quintana, Pablo 
and Kuester, Keith and Rubio-Ram{\'\i}rez, Juan},
journal={The American Economic Review},
volume={105},
number={11},
pages={3352--3384},
year={2015},
publisher={American Economic Association}
howpublished = {http://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20121236}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\citet*{fernandez2015fiscal} look at \ldots 

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `urlbst` on overleaf

Comment: @user191948, I am not. It's not in my MWE because I saw it wasn't working. I am curious though --  why it doesn't work on Overleaf? And is there another way to include URLs with `ecta` style?

Comment: `urlbst` is not a classic latex package, it is more a perl script that changes things in bst files. I doubt overleaf will allow their users to run such scripts

Comment: @user191948, good to know. I wasn't aware of that. Why do you doubt if Overleaf will let users run `perl` scripts? Are there any security reasons?

Comment: yes, security...

Comment: For me using `note` works with `ecta`, i.e., the url is displayed properly in the bibliography (however, `howpublished` does not work). Do you get any errors or warnings from BibTeX?

Comment: @Marijn, I just checked and this time `ecta` style works with `note`. I guess the first time round I tried `ecta` with URLs, I used both `howpublished` and `note` but wasn't wrapping the URL with `\url{}`. When I did wrap, it still didn't work with `howpublished` but it does work with `note`. Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an emergency hack, you could add the internet address to the pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=red]{hyperref}
\title{A Paper} 
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{fernandez2015fiscal,
title={Fiscal Volatility Shocks and Economic Activity},
author={Fern{\'a}ndez-Villaverde, Jes{\'u}s and Guerr{\'o}n-Quintana, Pablo 
and Kuester, Keith and Rubio-Ram{\'\i}rez, Juan},
journal={The American Economic Review},
volume={105},
number={11},
pages={3352--3384 \url{http://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20121236}},
year={2015},
publisher={American Economic Association}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\citet*{fernandez2015fiscal} look at \ldots 

\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did but it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks, @user19148. It certainly gets the job done. I wonder if there's a better or more efficient way of doing it but in any case, it does the job.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the other answer, and in comments, using `\url` within a BibTeX `note` field is probably the best you can do with stock BibTeX style files.

I can add to that a comment on `urlbst` (I'm its author).

As @user191948 noted, `urlbst` isn't a LaTeX package, so you can't ‘use’ it with `\usepackage`.  Instead, it's a Perl script, which will adapt (well, hack) pre-existing BibTeX style files, to create a *new* style which has a `url` and `lastpublished` field, and a new `@webpage` entry type.

That is,

```
urlbst ecta.bst ecta-url.bst
```

creates a style file called `ecta-url.bst`, which you can use with `\bibliographystyle{ecta-url}` as you might expect.  I've just done this locally, and verified that the script does appear to work OK with the ECTA style file, in the practical sense that BibTeX doesn't object to `ecta-url.bst`.  The edits that `urlbst` makes are rather heuristic in nature, so it's not guaranteed to work on ‘odd’ style files, which don't have one of the standard style files in their pretty immediate lineage.

I've only used Overleaf once or twice, but perhaps you can do this, and include your `ecta-url.bst` file amongst your project source files.